# Text color doesnot change in Maps Info window

Tags: java, css, google-maps, gwt, stylesheet

I am trying to customize text in google maps info window. I have a CSS file which has the following:

```
.zabove {color:#ff0000; font-weight: bold;} // red and bold
.zbelow {color:#14d714;} // green
```

And in the java class depending on a value for foo, I try to set the color of a label by using the setStyle method:

```
if(foo>100){
    label.setStyle("zbove");
} else {
    label.setStyle("zbelow");
```

The above does not result me any color, the text is just black.

Comment: Looks like you're missing an `a` in `setStyle("zbove")`. Should probably be: `label.setStyle("zabove");`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What browser are you using. Try using different browser. What you are doing looks absolutely correct. Sometimes I have found the GWT application behaves differently on different browsers.

Comment: Oh, is it browser specific. I was using FF it did not work, but when I use in IE it works fine. Strange.